# Jetty: How to write to access logs

Tags: java, logging, servlets, jetty

In my Java servlet code, I want to be able to programatically write to the jetty access log.  I am aware that jetty will automatically log every incoming HTTP request to the access log.  However, my servlet needs to occasionally append it's own line to the access log.  Has anyone here done something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think Lispnik is on the right track.  You want to get a handle on the NCSARequestLog described in http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Logging+Requests and send log messages directly to it, by calling log().  So you want to find the place in your code that's currently configuring the NCSARequestLog and substitute a modified version of the code that will return the pointer to the log it created.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone stumbles here searching for the same thing, it is yet another of those things that jetty does easily, but the documentation is poor for. Anyway, for Jetty 9, you just add `jetty-requestlog.xml`, which is a file in `$JETTY_HOME/etc/` to `$JETTY_HOME/etc/jetty.conf` to get a basic request log going. You must restart your server for the config to take effect, of course.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, another way to accomplish the same in Jetty 9 is to add the three lines following (from [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Request_Logs)) in the `"Handlers"` section in `$JETTY_HOME/etc/jetty.xml`:

```
<Item>
    <New id="RequestLog" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler"/>
</Item>
```

and the, at the *end* of the `"Handlers"` section, add the following code:

```
<Ref id="RequestLog">
  <Set name="requestLog">
    <New id="RequestLogImpl" class="org.eclipse.jetty.NCSARequestLog">
     <Arg><SystemProperty name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</Arg>
      <Set name="retainDays">90</Set>
      <Set name="append">true</Set>
      <Set name="extended">false</Set>
      <Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>
     </New>
  </Set>
</Ref>
```

That is, make those sections look like the section "Configuring the Request Logs for a Jetty Server" in this [page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Request_Logs).

Answer (score 0):

Subclass and configure: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Logging+Requests